# Merge and get Identity on Insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I need to merge new items in `#temp_table` into a `table_a`.

There is also a `parent_table`, which has a primary key identity column `parent_table_id` (and `table_a` has a corresponding foreign-key column for a `parent_table_id`). Each item in `table_a` points to a corresponding entry in the parent table.

So for each item in `#temp_table`, I need to insert into both `table_a` and `parent_table`.

The problem is, suppose I merge into the `parent_table` first, how do I get all of the corresponding `parent_table_id` items to set in all the `table_a` inserts? I was thinking of adding a `parent_table_id` column to `#temp_table`, initially set to null, then filling it up with values after the merge, but I'm not quite sure how to go about this. There is no other unique column in `parent_table` that can be used to select the new columns after they are inserted, other than the `parent_table_id`.

Comment: Check the [`OUTPUT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx?ppud=4) clause. It works for INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE and MERGE statements, handles multiple rows, and offers access to _before_ and _after_ data, as applicable.

Comment: @HABO Neat, looks promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a generic way of doing it (stripped down):

```
MERGE parent_table AS TARGET
USING @temp_table AS SOURCE
ON
(
    TARGET.match_number = SOURCE.match_Number
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
    (
        item1,
        item2,
        item3
    )
    VALUES
    (
        SOURCE.item1, 
        SOURCE.item2, 
        SOURCE.item3, 
    )
OUTPUT INSERTED.parent_table_id, SOURCE.reference_number INTO @Ids (parent_table_id, reference_number);
```

Results in @Ids containing all the parent table ids with other important info from the source which can be used elsewhere (i.e. for joining into table_a).